# Should people be expected to explain details to those who haven't seen the film or show?

Tags: discussion

I've seen comments where people ask things since they haven't seen it. Should that be taken seriously on Movies & TV SE?

For example, this question: [Is it common to see diversity of backgrounds shown in locations where You Are So Not Invited to My Bat Mitzvah takes place?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/120912/is-it-common-to-see-diversity-of-backgrounds-shown-in-locations-where-you-are-so)

In the above question, there are comments asking about the location of where the movie was set. Should the OP give every movie detail requested in the comments? If someone has seen it and they forget a small detail, that seems fine, but what about something that is made clear throughout the whole movie?

Should the OP be required to furnish any commonly known (for those who've seen it) details upon request for those who haven't seen the movie? Questions aren't going to provide details about context, possible nuance, or things they miss (which are sometimes what questions are about).

To be clear, **this ultimately comes down to whether a question can be closed based solely on some people not seeing it and wanting more information or not.**

Comment: Are you referring to this question of yours? [Is the motivation behind the villain's actions in Bon Cop Bad Cop somewhat relatable?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/121095/1006)

Comment: I'm referring to any question

Comment: I saw examples here

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/120912/is-it-common-to-see-diversity-of-backgrounds-shown-in-locations-where-you-are-so

Comment: Though yeah the question I put someone asked for spoiler alerts. If someone doesn't want to bother with answers from people who haven't seen it, should they?

Comment: Like what other SE says, 'knowledge of the subject is not required' lol

Comment: My question was closed for opinion based, which is different. I'm not trying to get it unclosed here.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to be a little clearer what you talking about here. As it stands, I have *zero* idea what *"people ask things since they haven't seen it"* really means.

Comment: You can see comments in the example I linked. Like asking about location. Like really, you want someone to give you every movie detail requested? If someone has seen it, and they forget a small detail, ok, but something that is made clear the whole movie, like what.

Comment: If this is the case, that someone should be required to furnish any commonly known (for those who've seen it) details upon request for those who haven't seen it, ok, but that seriously tarnishes the credibility of a site on movies and tv. Like why would anyone trust the answers? Questions aren't going to provide details about context and possible nuance, or things they miss (which are sometimes what questions are about).

Comment: Or at least there can be a flag, saying whether watching the film is required or not.  When it is required, people shouldn't comment asking for basic details.

Comment: I note that OP marked their account for deletion *before* posting this question, so I doubt they were too interested in listening to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: It's not *generally* necessary, but in cases like this, where it seems as though there are no other active users that *have* seen the film, then it becomes necessary, as the alternative is forcing people to watch the film just to understand the question. If those details aren't provided, then closing the question is perfectly justified, and it can always be reopened if someone comes along who *has* seen the film.

---

I'll start by noting that users are perfectly allowed to answer ([and ask!](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2648/46980)) questions about movies or TV shows they haven't seen. I've done this myself, on occasions where watching the movie isn't strictly required, such as [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/92447/46980). Of course, this leaves the possibility of users posting answers that are misinformed or flat-out wrong, but we have existing quality systems in place to deal with such answers (i.e. commenting, downvoting, and deleting).

In the case of your specific question, I feel the problem isn't the lack of description, per se. As you've alluded to, it's generally neither needed nor expected to explain a movie in intricate detail, as enough users will have seen the movie to be able to fill in the blanks.

The problem here is that, as far as I can tell, **this isn't the case here**. *Bon Cop, Bad Cop* appears to be very obscure outside of Quebec, and - again, as far as I can tell - there's no indication that anyone who's seen your question so far has even *heard* of it, let alone seen it. I certainly hadn't.

Now, I'm not going to pretend that this isn't a bad thing. It's an inherent flaw of Stack Exchange, and pretty much any other similar resource on the Internet, that the more obscure a question's subject is, especially in the Anglosphere, the less likely it is to be answered. You're by no means the first user to fall victim to this - you already highlighted one example in the comments, and I recall seeing several questions about Bollywood movies go unanswered over the years.

So if nobody on the site appears to be familiar with the work you're asking about, you have two options:

1. Provide more details about the work
2. Insist that users *have* to watch the work before they can answer

I understand that 2) is your preferred option, and I understand why - you're concerned that there might be nuances to the answer that one can only pick up on if they've watched the film. But here on Stack Exchange, 1) is very much the preferred option. Users shouldn't be required to spend two hours of their lives watching a film just to be able to understand a question about it, and in the case of a TV show, they *definitely* shouldn't be required to watch five seasons of it. The onus is on the person asking the question to ensure it contains all the necessary details, which should generally take them only a few minutes.

And in the case of your specific question, I honestly don't believe that watching the film *is* necessary. Your question can be summarized as:

> In *Bon Cop, Bad Cop*, the villain performs action X due to motivation Y. Is it realistic for a person to do X because of Y, and are there any real-life examples of it?

As long as we know what X and Y are, then I honestly don't see why we'd need to watch the film to be able to answer that. Again, I understand that you're concerned about nuance, but I don't see what nuance there could possibly be here: it's a very straightforward question. And again, if someone does come up with an answer that you know to be wrong, or at least missing some nuance, you can leave comments so that the user can correct their answer (or, at the very least, anyone else visiting the question will know what the problem is with that answer).

> this ultimately comes down to whether a question can be closed based solely on some people not seeing [the film] and wanting more information or not.

**Yes.** If nobody on the site is familiar with the film, and OP is unwilling to provide more details about it (as was the case here), then closing it as "unclear what you're asking" is absolutely justified. That said, if someone comes along who *has* seen the film, then the question can always be reopened so they can post an answer.